# jQuery - Parse & convert markedup text

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

With jQuery how can I convert this text

```
The quick]] brown [[fox]] jumps over the lazy [[dogs [[back]]
```

into that

```
The quick]] brown <span class="gist">fox</span> jumps over the lazy <span class="gist">dogs [[back</span>
```

?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isn't it better like that ?

```
str.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, '<span class="gist">$1</span>');
```

Comment: Any comment on my proposition (that worked for me) and my votes down ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use javascript:

```
var string = "The quick brown [[fox]] jumps over the lazy [[dogs back]]"
string = string.replace(/\[\[/g, '<span class="gist">').replace(/\]\]/g, '</span>');
```

This is using regex to find `[[` and replace it with `<span class="gist">` and then find `]]` and replace it with `</span>`. Because `[` and `]` are both special characters in regex they have to be escaped with a backslash (`\`), and we want the replace to be global (eg: replace more than one instance), which gives us: `/\[\[/g` and `/\]\]/g`.

---

If you need to handle unclosed brackets, you'll have to go with something different, like a state machine:

```
var string = "The quick]] brown [[fox]] jumps over the lazy [[dogs [[back]]";
var state = 'NO_TAG';
var parts = [];
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    if(string[i] === "[" && string[i+1] === "[" && state === 'NO_TAG') {
        parts.push('<span class="gist">');
        i += 1;
        state = 'TAG';
    } else if (state === 'TAG' && string[i] === "[" && string[i+1] === "[") {
        i += 1; // ignore start brackets if we are in a tag.
    } else if (state === 'TAG' && string[i] === "]" && string[i+1] === "]") {
        parts.push('</span>');
        i += 1;
        state = 'NO_TAG';
    } else if (state === 'NO_TAG' && string[i] === ']' && string[i+1] === ']') {
        i += 1; // ignore end brackets if we are not in a tag.
    } else {
        parts.push(string[i]);
    }
}

string = parts.join('');
```

I won't guarantee that this state machine will work in all cases, but it works with your test string.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion, too.

Comment: The problem is if there are unclosed brackets it will generate unclosed HTML. Look at my updated question.

Comment: Well, you don't need regex to replace one set, but without regex you can't do a global replace, so the second set of brackets won't be changed. As far as unclosed html, the only thing I can say is make sure not to have unclosed brackets. The only way I can think of to get around that is if you never want to enclose more than one word, then you could do it with a state machine (or a split by space I suppose...) and just close the tag at the end of the word, whether you find the closing brackets or not.

Comment: Also I don't want to skip the enclosed brackets so the state machine should be simplified. Isn't it a way to regex this with a recursive function ?